# Function definition not found in 4gl file

Tags: informix, 4gl

I am working on 4gl language but a new bie. In a file custom.4gl a function cleanup() is called, but I didn't find the function definition. I am trying to find that.

I got a file named 'tags' with following line of code in which a hint for cleanup is there. But I didn't understand what this meant. Can anyone help me to find the function definition.

I folder searched with my code editor but there was no way.

```
cleanup custom.4gl  /^function cleanup(
cn_error_handler    cnerhand.4gl    /^function cn_error_handler(
default_code    custom.4gl  /^function default_code(
get_file    custom.4gl  /^function get_file(
get_params  custom.4gl  /^function get_params(
get_prompts custom.4gl  /^function get_prompts(
logo    main.4gl    /^function logo(
```

Comment: What Informix 4gl version do you use ?

Comment: 1.20 ? I think there was never such a version. What Informix product do you use?

Comment: Propably cleanup() is in another source file. You can "link" several compiled 4gl files into one executable. You may have a "library" file functions to share (and link) with 4gl programs.

Comment: Which platform?  I4GL 1.20 was not a version I remember, but it might have existed as a PC-DOS version (in the days before there was a thing called Windows!).  But we're talking about geriatric software — way over twenty years old.  Please double check the version (`i4gl -V`) and confirm the platform.

Comment: On the face of it, the function `cleanup` should be (was once) in the file `custom.4gl`.  The tags file contains a function name, a file name, and a regex to look for the function in the file.  Do you have the source under a VCS (version control system).  If not, why not!  If so, review the recent changes to `custom.4gl`.

Answer (score 1):

The function cleanup used to be in custom.4gl.

If it's not there now, then someone must have deleted it.

Do you have some sort of source code control system that you might be able to get it from?

Answer (score 1):

what i usually do:

run executable in debugger and break for this function and it tells you the name of .4gl file its defined.

break cleanup

Comment: Hmmm...interesting...I was assuming that the program either didn't link or didn't run because of the missing function; you're assuming that the program runs, but the problem is locating the source file that contributes the function.  Under your assumption, your suggestion is reasonable.